# Block Packets from Specific IP's OpenVPN Linux Server

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

When I WFH I connect my home router to an OpenVPN server I built using an old Linux machine in my office. This works very well, but there are a few devices I have at home that I don't want to access the internet while my router is connected to the VPN.

I can identify these devices on the VPN server by IP address. Does anyone know how I can configure the OpenVPN server to block data for specific IP Addresses?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too few information, but the answer is probably: you can't, but you can connect to openvpn directly from your computer.